# Text interpreted as boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas with read_csv. It interprets strings as boolean if all values are either "true" or "false". How can I prevent this?

My `data.csv` file content:

```
String1,String2
true,false
true,false
true,true
```

Code

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv", true_values=None, false_values=None)
```

`None` for `true_values` and `false_values` should be default and leaving it out gives the same result. The value of df is:

```
  String1 String2
0    True   False
1    True   False
2    True    True
```

If my datafile contains a value other than "true" or "false" it does interpret the data as string. E.g. `data.csv` content:

```
String1,String2
true,false
true,nazca
true,true
```

gives for `df`:

```
  String1 String2
0    True   false
1    True   nazca
2    True    true
```

How do I get to read a string even when the data seems to be all boolean values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the dtype parameter as object:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", dtype="O")
```

This will treat all columns as objects. If you want to apply this only to those particular columns, you can pass a dictionary:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", dtype={"String1": "O", "String2": "O"})
```